# Como fazer essa função calcular com virgula em vez de ponto?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#somar").click(function(){
    var total = 0;
    var desconto = $("#desconto").val() != "" ? $("#desconto").val() : 0;
    $('.input').each(function(){
      var valor = Number($(this).val());
      if (!isNaN(valor)) total += valor;
    });
    total = total - desconto;
    $(".resultado").html(total.toFixed(2));
  });
});
</script>
<script>
  function imprimir(mesmo){
    var conteudo = mesmo.parentElement.innerHTML,
        tela_impressao = window.open('about:blank');

    tela_impressao.document.write(conteudo);
    tela_impressao.window.print();
    tela_impressao.window.close();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Você não consegue calcular com VIRGULA, o que consegue fazer é transformar o ponto em virgula no retorno da função. Veja a função [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) do JS

Comment: Como faço isso?

Comment: var str = "5,8";
var str = str.replace(",", ".");

Comment: Agora em qual parte do código?

Comment: Deixa eu explicar esses valores já ficam em um input que é recebido de outro fomulário eu queria fazer após clicar em calcular sem colocar os valores no input!